# What is the largest file size possible for a 1 second midi

Tags: midi

If the most stuff allowed was happening within 1 second, how big would the file be? As in if it was very busy for 1 second, maximally busy?

I thought about trying to really understand the format but it's a little beyond my level right now.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's 25-31kb/s based on the bit rate. It didn't occur to me that would probably be the same rate as the on disk size per second but, of course it kind of would be. Sorry internet.